# How to remove "./public/" from webpack manifest.json

Tags: javascript, webpack, manifest

I am creating a build using Webpack and added [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) to create `manifest.json` file. My compiling is working fine but it generates the file list like this.

```
{
  "common/css/labs.css": "./public/ubp/common/css/labs.dae7800e041a37e79c23.min.css",
  "common/js/alephbet.js": "./public/ubp/common/js/alephbet.14d37b43f6dd3b9304d4.min.js",
  "custom/my/js/main.js": "./public/ubp/custom/my/js/main.8d2e8dd0bf31570ccbc9.min.js"
}
```

**Manifest plugin configuration** is:

```
new manifestPlugin({
            'options': {
                writeToFileEmit: true,
                basePath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
            },
            // publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
            fileName: './public/manifest.json',
        })
```

I want to remove the `./public` from the value of manifest.json file. Can't find any option for that.

Comment: I believe [`publicPath`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin#publicpath) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @OrB thanks. it worked.